# PHP timestamp for if-modified-since with timezone

Tags: php, datetime, timestamp, if-modified-since

I have timestamp stored in MySQL in following format:

```
$if_modified_since = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

The timestamp is saved using server's default timezone which in my case is `EST`. I need to send a `CURL` request with `if-modified-since` header.

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("If-Modified-Since: ".gmdate('D, d M Y H:i:s \G\M\T',$if_modified_since)));
```

What will be the most optimal way for me to convert time in `EST` to `GMT`? Also is there a way to make it totally generic by checking the server timezone (instead of just hard-coding in `EST`)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked for me:

```
$d = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i:s', $if_modified_since, new DateTimeZone(ini_get('date.timezone'))); 
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("If-Modified-Since: ".gmdate('D, d M Y H:i:s \G\M\T',$d->getTimestamp())));
```